# How to run *.exe using CMD recursively?

Tags: python-2.7, cmd

I have an executable "nc2text.exe" which I am running through cmd with a set of options. For example:

```
nc2text.exe ifile.nc temperature > ofile.txt
```

I have to repeat this step many times and wondering if I can automate it either using cmd or python script. Any suggestions?

Comment: You mean running the exact same command many times ?

Comment: Yes, but input and output file names will change.

Comment: Input will be ifile1, ifile2.... and output file names will be likeweise

Answer (score 0):

**Python:**

```
import time
import subprocess

i = 0
def periodicTimer():
    subprocess.call("nc2text.exe ifile" + str(i) + ".nc temperature > ofile" + str(i) + ".txt")
    i = i+1
    time.sleep(60)

while True:
    periodicTimer()
```

I don't have that `nc2text.exe` on my machine but replacing the `subprocess` with a `print`:

```
print "nc2text.exe ifile" + str(i) + ".nc temperature > ofile" + str(i) + ".txt"
```

Outputs:

```
nc2text.exe ifile0.nc temperature > ofile0.txt
nc2text.exe ifile1.nc temperature > ofile1.txt
nc2text.exe ifile2.nc temperature > ofile2.txt
nc2text.exe ifile3.nc temperature > ofile3.txt
```

And so on...

**Batch:**

```
@echo off
cls
Set counter=0
:start
nc2text.exe ifile%counter%.nc temperature > ofile%counter%.txt
Set /A counter+=1
echo %counter%
timeout 5 /NOBREAK
goto start
:end
pause
```

Comment: I am not familiar with running batch on windows. So do I need to save above batch program in a file and run through cmd or else?

Comment: Create a batch file in notepad `example.bat`, copy paste the code snippet there, save, copy it to where `nc2text.exe` is, then run it from `cmd`

Comment: And change the `@echo off` to `@echo on`, it will help you debugging.

Comment: Batch option ran successfully. However following one file test failed: subprocess.call("nc2text.exe infile.nc temperature > test.txt")
time.sleep(30)

Comment: It initiates cmd but strangely returns nothing (no error message).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39770/discussion-between-ibe-and-ofiris)